# Laravel detect mass assigning

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a model event defined on a model that each time a create a record I add the user's company id related to that record.

All works fine but I'm mass assigning records through csv importation and I must set the company id set as null.

How can I detect in Laravel when I'm massive assigning?

This is my model event:

```
protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function (Product $model) {
            $model->company_owner_id = session()->get('currentCompany.id');
        });
    }
```

I've not done the controller's function that stores the records created through CRUD form neither the csv importer and both are strongly used by all the Laravel app so I have no chance to modify the importer or CRUD form.

Before using the csv importer the $fillable attribute on the model wasn't defined.

Comment: You can overload the create method of the model and change it to your liking.

Comment: You mean, you want to set the `company_owner_id` to company owner id when you create single model normally in your code base; but you want it to be `null` when mass assigning from csv importer?

Comment: Yes that’s exactly what I want

Comment: There is one option which I don't know if it is the best way or not, it is to add a flag property `withCompanyOwner` to your model class, and inside your `static::creating` just use it in an if condition and so on. But you must set this variable before creating a model which is a hassle by itself! (Not a clean solution but works).

Comment: Also note that, the mass assignment `create` simply creates a new instance and uses `save` so no event is triggered in where you can detect if record was created normally or by mass assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I gave up on this and stopped to add the company_id on records as I can not determinate whether the records are created through csv importation or CRUD form.

Answer (score -1):

You can take your model and add the array ['company_owner_id'] to the fillables for this model. If you put your creating logic in the import controller rather than the service provider, it will only run from there.

```
protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function (Product $model) {
            $now_fillable=['company_owner_id'];
            $model->mergeFillable($now_fillable);
            $model->company_owner_id = session()->get('currentCompany.id');
        });
    }
```